# Custom tag in playframework2.0 or perform equals in a template

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I need to perform an equals comparison in my template, inorder to do a conditional render.

For instance, I have `<li class="active">`. In here, I would like active only to be rendered if `@request.path` and `@controllers.routes.Application.action()` are equal, otherwise a blank string is fine.

the if statement as described in [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplates) appears to be limited in recognizing the paranthesis and hence does not work.

Alternatively if you could help me with creating a custom tag, that could also work. There is no documentation on how to do that. I'll prefer java. If there is a scala alternative, please err on the side of verbosity as I have yet to figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a custom tag, you can try something like this in your template :

```
<li class="@("active".when(request.path == controllers.routes.Application.action().toString()))">
```

There is an example in samples applications (samples/java/forms/app/views/main.scala.html).
**Dont forget the toString() because action() returns a Call, not a String).**

A custom tag to do that could be :

```
@menu_element(name: String, route: Call) = {
 <li class="@("active".when(route.toString() == request.path))"><a href="@route">@name</a></li>
}
```

Example of use :

```
<ul>
 @menu_element("Home", controllers.routes.Application.index)
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. I used the tag version, and made a minor change. `@Messages(name)` and passed the i18n code. also put the tag in a separate file so removed the `menu_element`